# Want to sync department

Tags: filter, microsoft-graph-api, synchronization

Hey i want to sync members via their department normally i would use this filter

```
startsWith(department, 'A') or startsWith(department, 'B')
```

and so on

but in this case there is one department which i dont want to sync is there a filter for that? i thought something like that would work
`(not(startsWith(department, 'E')))` but that dosen't work.

someone got a solution?

was trying a few filters and want to sync only members of the department that starts without 'E'

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about users endpoint then the filtering will work only in case you add header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` and `$count=true`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=department&$filter=not(startswith(department,'E'))&$count=true
```

Docs:

[Advanced query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http)

Comment: hey i've tried this filter but it says that the filter operator "NOT" is not supported any ideas?

Comment: @Yezz the message that "Filter operator 'Not' is not supported." can appear in case of missing request header ConsistencyLevel with value eventual.

Comment: i understand thank you the problem is i have no way to set a Advanced query in my environment is there a solution without the advanced query?

Comment: @Yezz I think that adding request header should be possible in all environments. What's your environment?